# Schema for JSON object with an array of items of the same type when this type is different in different objects

Tags: json, jsonschema

I want to describe schema of an object which has a property of array type. Items in that array must be of the same type. But two different objects can have different type for items in that array:

```
// object_1
{
  <...>,
  "array_of_some_type": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  <...>
}

// object_2
{
  <...>,
  "array_of_some_type": ["one", "two", "three"],
  <...>
}
```

I have tried using of `oneOf` keyword:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    <...>
    "array_of_some_type": {
      "type": "array",
      "minItems": 1,
      "uniqueItems": true,
      "items": {
        "oneOf": [
          { "type": "number" },
          { "type": "string" },
          { "type": "object" }
        ]
      },
      "additionalItems": false
    },
    <...>
  },
  "required": [ "array_of_some_type" ],
  "additionalProperties": false
}
```

But it is wrong because this schema is valid for invalid in my case object:

```
// invalid_object
{
  <...>,
  "array_of_some_type": [1, "two", 3],
  <...>
}
```

The correct schema can look like:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    <...>
    "array_of_some_type": {
      "oneOf": [
        {
          "type": "array",
          "minItems": 1,
          "uniqueItems": true,
          "items": { "type": "number" },
          "additionalItems": false
        },
        {
          "type": "array",
          "minItems": 1,
          "uniqueItems": true,
          "items": { "type": "string" },
          "additionalItems": false
        },
        {
          "type": "array",
          "minItems": 1,
          "uniqueItems": true,
          "items": { "type": "object" },
          "additionalItems": false
        }
      ]
    },
    <...>
  },
  "required": [ "array_of_some_type" ],
  "additionalProperties": false
}
```

BUT there are a lot of duplicates of identical array's properties.
Is there any way to tune the second schema to avoid repetitions? Or any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put only the part that varies in the `oneOf` clause.  I think JSON-Schema would have to support something like Java's generics in order to express this any cleaner.

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "array_of_some_type": {
      "type": "array",
      "minItems": 1,
      "uniqueItems": true,
      "oneOf": [
        { "items": { "type": "number" } },
        { "items": { "type": "string" } },
        { "items": { "type": "object" } }
      ]
    }
  },
  "required": [ "array_of_some_type" ],
  "additionalProperties": false
}
```

Comment: Better to use anyOf in most cases - it will validate faster in most implementations. oneOf is only valid if exactly one option is valid, so validator will have to validate all of them. anyOf is valid if any option is valid so as soon as the validator finds the option that is valid it will stop.

Comment: @esp, good point.  Both `oneOf` and `anyOf` would work in this case and `anyOf` would have better validation performance.

Comment: But schema with `oneOf` will validate object like `{ "array_of_some_type": [1, "two", 3] }` which is not valid in my case. Or am I wrong? That is why I made a schema with `anyOf`, but it has a lot of duplicates. So I am looking for a solution which will validate only correct objects and will not have too much duplicates.

Comment: @OlegCh, try it and you will see that the schema I have proposed does what you want it to do.  Your example will not validate using this schema.  Try it with both `anyOf` and `oneOf`.  You will see that they work exactly the same.

Comment: @Jason, you are right! That was my misunderstanding of how validation with `oneOf` works. So, if `oneOf` or `anyOf` is specified inside array definition then it will be chosen once for the first element and then applied to all other items?

Comment: @OlegCh, think about it like there are 4 different array schemas. The first is an array of unique items with at least 1 item. It does not restrict the items. The schemas in the `oneOf` are also array schemas, but they only define what type of items the array can have. In order for an array to validate against `array_of_some_type`, it must validate against the first array schema and one of the three `oneOf` array schemas. Since none of the `oneOf` schemas define an array that allows for items of more than one type, the overall array can not have items of more than one type.